# Dynamodb - Inexact: [<class 'decimal.Inexact'>, <class 'decimal.Rounded'>]

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm absolutely lost with this error I'm getting trying to upload to DynamoDb. I'm trying to upload a Shodan API response to a table.

```
response = [{<nested_JSON>}, {<nested_JSON>}, {<nested_JSON>}]

for i in response:
    test = loads(dumps(item), parse_float=Decimal)
    old_dic_with_decimals = replace_decimals(test)
    new_dict_with_decimals_as_strings = loads(dumps(old_dic_with_decimals))
    dynamodb.table.put_item(Item=new_dict_with_decimals_as_strings)
```

But I'm getting this error on the `put_item` funciton.

`[ERROR] Inexact: [<class 'decimal.Inexact'>, <class 'decimal.Rounded'>]`

I've printed the output an can confirm there are no Decimal classes in the response. Here is my function to convert Decimals to strings:

```
def replace_decimals(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        for i in range(len(obj)):
            obj[i] = replace_decimals(obj[i])
        return obj
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        for k, v in obj.items():
            obj[k] = replace_decimals(obj[k])
        return obj
    elif isinstance(obj, Decimal):
        ctx = Context(prec=4)
        # In my original code I'm converting to int or float, comment the line above if necessary.
        if obj % 1 == 0:
            my_decimal = ctx.create_decimal_from_float(int(obj))
            obj = str(my_decimal)
            return obj
        else:
            my_decimal = ctx.create_decimal_from_float(float(obj))
            obj = str(my_decimal)
            return obj
    else:
        return obj
```

I'm lost as to why Dynamodb is throwing this error. There is absolute no Decimals in the response I'm trying to send to Dynamodb. I've tried just about every suggestion I can find on stack overflow with no luck. Any help here would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue after finding this monkey patch on github: https://gist.github.com/lbenitez000/85fb43e40a7839e13405

Essentially you have to add this:

```
# Monkey patch Decimal's default Context to allow 
# inexact and rounded representation of floats
import decimal
from boto.dynamodb.types import DYNAMODB_CONTEXT
# Inhibit Inexact Exceptions
DYNAMODB_CONTEXT.traps[decimal.Inexact] = 0
# Inhibit Rounded Exceptions
DYNAMODB_CONTEXT.traps[decimal.Rounded] = 0
```

this will allow Inexact and Rounded representation of floats! Hope this helps someone else in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

I know you mention not finding any decimals in your response, but this is for those who actually have something like that. I stumbled on this answer when I searched for that error code.

A value that I was passing to be sent to dynamoDB was this 185.1851851851852 and of type float. I converted it to Decimal with

```py
from decimal import Decimal
Decimal(185.1851851851852)
```

But the issue persisted. So it popped into my head to have fewer decimal places (which I was supposed to have anyway XD) because the error mentions something about rounding. That did the trick. [Python Decimal FAQ](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal-faq)

```py
from decimal import Decimal
TWOPLACES = Decimal(10) ** -2   # same as Decimal('0.01')
Decimal(185.1851851851852).quantize(TWOPLACES)
# 185.19
```